# failed to set database initializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC5 to make a website. I created several classes in the model folder and used "scaffolding feature" in Entity Framework to create CRUD pages. Everything is fine in the Home page. But when I clicked the "Employee" link in the navigation bar, there was an error in this line:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Employees.ToList());
}
```

The error is:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Failed to set database initializer of type 'wms.DAL.ProductInitilizer, wms' for DbContext type 'wms.DAL.ProductContext, wms' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.
```

Here is `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Post { get; set; }
    public string PS { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Delivery> Deliveries { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
}
```

part of `ProductInitializer`:

```
namespace wms.DAL
{
    public class ProductInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ProductContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ProductContext context)
        {
            ...
            var employees = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee{ID="238047AF1",Name="Bill",Department="Storage",Post="worker",PS="default"},
                new Employee{ID="2457656AB",Name="Bob",Department="Storage",Post="worker",PS="default"}
            };
            employees.ForEach(s => context.Employees.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="wms" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What's wrong here? I've been digging for a long time but couldn't find the reason.

---

**Update**

inner exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Failed to set database initializer of type 'wms.DAL.ProductInitilizer, wms' for DbContext type 'wms.DAL.ProductContext, wms' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type requiredContextType, String contextTypeName, String initializerTypeName, Boolean isDisabled, Func`1 initializerArgs, Func`3 exceptionMessage)
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.<>c__DisplayClass6.<TryGetInitializerFromEntityFrameworkSection>b__1(ContextElement e)
       System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializerFromEntityFrameworkSection(Type contextType)
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type contextType)
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name)
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 t)
       System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
       System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
       System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService(IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Type type)
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
       System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
       System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       wms.Controllers.EmployeeController.Index() Location c:\Users\cityofsky\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\wms\wms\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs:Line 21
       lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException: System.TypeLoadException
       HResult=-2146233054
       Message=Could not load type "wms.DAL.ProductInitilizer" from assembly "wms"
       Source=mscorlib
       TypeName=wms.DAL.ProductInitilizer
       StackTrace:
            System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
            System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
            System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)
            System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type requiredContextType, String contextTypeName, String initializerTypeName, Boolean isDisabled, Func`1 initializerArgs, Func`3 exceptionMessage)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Check the message of the inner exception, and post it

Comment: @MarcCals Thank you. Posted just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You posted the wrong web.config. Post the one in the root of your project. Though the database initializer can also be inside your global.asax.

But what i see is that the exception refers to 'ProductInitilizer' while the name of the class with the initializer is 'ProductInitializer'. Typo is the problem?

Comment: Yes, typo is the problem, you are so amazing. Thank you!